# Is it possible to add links liked via a facebook like button to a category?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm working on a movie site and i want links liked via a facebook like button to be added to the movie category. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just set "movie" as the "og:type" attribute in the meta tags on the page referenced in your Like button's href parameter.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
```

More on defining Facebook "types":
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#types

Answer (score 0):

As long as that category has a separate URL with a page that can be scraped by Facebook, yes. You can create a like for that.